# Automatically convert date to datetime in sqlite using pyodbc

Tags: python, sqlite, pyodbc

I'm using sqlite for testing purposes together with pyodbc. I noticed that when selecting, if I supply '2014-12-31' it will get strictly treated as a date rather than datetime.

```
import pyodbc

db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=:memory:')
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute('create table test (quote_date datetime, unique_id int)')
cur.commit()

cur.execute('insert into test values ("2014-12-31", 1)')
cur.execute('insert into test values ("2014-12-31 00:00:00", 2)')
cur.commit()

print(cur.execute('select * from test where quote_date = "2014-12-31"').fetchall())
```

The above example gives the output:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1)]
```

Rather than the two rows. Any idea how I can make '2014-12-31' and '2014-12-31 00:00:00' equivalent?